# Find an ArrayList Object - Search not working?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a Bank that can deposit, withdraw, create account, and display all the balances.

My createButton method works fine -

```
    public void createNewAccountButtonPanel(){
    //create button
    createButton = new JButton("Create New Account");
    //Add Listener modeled from InputFrame.Java from GroupProject
    class AddCreateNewListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent CreateNew){
            //account number has to be 4 digits. Balance has to be 100 or more
            if(accountField.getText().trim().length() != 4 || balanceField.getText().trim().length() < 3){
                //not correct input, tell the user to enter the correct input
                System.out.println("Failed to create a Bank Account!");
                textArea.append("Please enter a Account number and a Balance!" + "\n");
            }
            else
            {//read the input
                System.out.println("Creating a Bank Account!");
                Integer accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(accountField.getText());
                Double amount = Double.parseDouble(balanceField.getText());
                getBank().createNew(accountNumber, amount);
                textArea.append("You created " + getBank().accounts.get(getBank().accounts.size()-1) + "   \n");
            }
            }   
    }
    createNew = new AddCreateNewListener();
    createButton.addActionListener(createNew);  
}
```

Here is my search - It always returns null, even if I know I have added an account...

```
    public BankAccount search(Integer accountNumber){
    BankAccount found = null;
    for(BankAccount a : accounts){
        if(a.getAccountNumber() == accountNumber) {
            System.out.println("Found the account!");
            found = a;     
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The Account Number you entered was not found.");
            found = null;
        }
    }       
    return found;
}
```

What am I missing? This is also causing my Deposit and Withdraw buttons to now work. My display all accounts works just fine.

EDIT: It appears my search was working, I have added a `break`. Now the issue is getting the balance to show in the text area of a gui - It always shows 0.0

```
    public void displayBalancePanel(){
    //create the button
    displayBalanceButton = new JButton("Display The Balance");
    //Add listener modeled from InputFrame.java from GroupProject
    class AddDisplayBalanceListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent DisplayBalance){
            //read the input
            Integer accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(accountField.getText());
            System.out.println("accountNumber to Display Balance for: " + accountNumber);
            getBank().displayBalance(accountNumber, amount);
            textArea.append("The Balance for Account: " + accountNumber + " is " + getAmount() + "\n");
        }
    }
    displayBalance = new AddDisplayBalanceListener();
    displayBalanceButton.addActionListener(displayBalance);
}
```

New search -

```
    public BankAccount search(Integer accountNumber){
    BankAccount found = null;
    for(BankAccount a : accounts){
        if(a.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)) {
            System.out.println("Found the account!");
            found = a;     
            System.out.println("a: " + a);
            break;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The Account Number you entered was not found.");
            found = null;
        }
    }       
    return found;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact return type of `a.getAccountNumber()`?  `Integer`?  `int`?

Comment: getAccountNumber() returns int

Answer (score 0):

When you have found the account, your `for` loop keeps going past the desired `Account`.  Then the `else` sets `found` back to `null`.

When you have found the account, just return it from right there in the `if` block.  You don't even need an `else` block.

In fact, you don't need the variable `found` at all.  Just return `a` directly in the `if` block, and the last statement in the method can be changed to `return null;` if it wasn't found.

Comment: Thank you, I have modified it to 'break' once it finds the account. I will clean this up once we get the other parts working